# LaTeX conditionals to change linespacing dependent on title length

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I'm attempting to define my own beamer package in LaTeX.  I've run into a small problem whereby if my title overlaps onto a second line then the rest of the text is pushed downwards.

I was hoping I could fix this with an if statement but Googling hasn't resulted in anything too helpful.  I would like to say something along the lines of:

if (title overlaps onto second line) then (start title higher up the page)

But I'm not sure how to write that in LaTeX.

Below is a working example...

This is the tex file:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Images/}}
    \title{This is my short title that looks nice...}
    \date[]{\today}
    \author[My name]{My name \hfill \texttt{My email} \\[.5em] My affiliation}

    \usetheme{mine}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Context}
        Test frame
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

and this is the beamerinnertheme file in which I define the titlepage and would like the if statement to be:

```
    \mode<presentation>

    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      % Top box.
      \fill[color=green!20!black!90] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,        \the\paperheight);
      % Left box.
      \fill[color=green!20!black!90] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.9);
      % Right box.
      \fill[color=green!20!black!90] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.9);
      % Makes page white if not on page 1 (i.e. title page).
      \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
       \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
       \fi
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
    \setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

    % Title page
    \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mine}[1][]
    {
       \vskip5.5cm%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{title page header}
          \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \vskip0.25cm%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
          \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip1.2cm%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
          \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
      \vfill
    }
```

This is an example that looks nice...
[image]

And this is one that doesn't work...
[image]

Comment: off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use any conditional for that. Just put the `\inserttitle` into a `\parbox[b][\f@size][b]{9cm}{\inserttitle}`. Change the width of that `\parbox` to your liking.

The complete theme-file becomes:

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  % Top box.
  \fill[color=green!20!black!90] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,        \the\paperheight);
  % Left box.
  \fill[color=green!20!black!90] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.9);
  % Right box.
  \fill[color=green!20!black!90] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.9);
  % Makes page white if not on page 1 (i.e. title page).
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
   \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
   \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mine}[1][]
{
   \vskip5.5cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{title page header}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\parbox[b][\f@size][b]{9cm}{\inserttitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip0.25cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip1.2cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
}
```

The following shows my results (sorry for black font -- the font file you use wasn't found on my machine).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer states, using `\parbox` is the preferred solution. However, if you do want to use conditionals (here or elsewhere in the template), it is not very difficult. You can store a box using `\savebox`, measure the size, and add the required amount of space.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% one of the following
\title{This is my short title that looks nice...}
\title{This is the longer title that ruins the stuff below...}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{coloredboxstuff}{fg=white,bg=green!20!black!90}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm]{coloredboxstuff}%
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\ifdim\ht\mybox>10pt\vskip2.5cm\else\vskip5.5cm\fi%
\usebox{\mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: As an addition, one could also add space based on the box space (not conditional but calculated) with something like: `\vskip0.5\ht\mybox` or even `\vskip\dimexpr0.5\ht\mybox-1in\relax`.